# How to parse the JSON response from URL in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, url

I am new to flutter and want to parse the data from a URL that is in json format. The url that I am using is [json link](http://quotes.rest/bible/vod.json) .
I want to get the "verse" and "chapter" fields from the json array. I have succeeded in getting the response body in snackbar but not able to get single values. I want to get the "verse" and "chapter" and show then in text box. I am using Dart.

Here is the method that I am using:

```
 _makeGetRequest() async {
    // make request
    var url = Uri.parse("http://quotes.rest/bible/vod.json");
    Response response = await http.get(url);

    // sample info available in response
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    Map<String, String> headers = response.headers;
    String contentType = headers['content-type'];
    String json = response.body;

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(json)));

  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamingController.config(url: "http://stream.zeno.fm/qa8p6uz2tk8uv");
    streamingController.play();
    _makeGetRequest();
  }
```

Please help me in getting the proper field values and set them in text box as I am trying to solve it from past two days and have tried all solutions from internet but getting exceptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to parse JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533880/flutter-how-to-parse-json-data)

Comment: How can I show it inside a text box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use jsonDecode

```
 Map<String,dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
 String verse = data["contents"]["verse"];
 dynamic chapter= data["contents"]["chapter"];
```

however I recommend modeling your data

Comment: Thank u it worked for me.. I am able to show it in snackbar .. But How can I show it in the text box as this is inside a method?

Comment: take a look at `FutureBuilder` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: and if previous answer solved your problem upvote and mark question as answered ;)

Comment: How can I return the verse string so it will be accessible in class?

Comment: `Future<String> _makeGetRequest() async {  await someApiWork(); return verse;  }`